# How to loops imacros using with javascript using extract element

Tags: javascript, imacros

I'm working on a imacro script which re-post content from my website to social websites.

*media_raw* check if there is new content. *raw* is the number of new posts.

The issue is that the loop is not working with *raw* variable as condition. Its working fine if I set a number manually.

```
var media_raw;
media_raw ="CODE:";
media_raw +="SET !ERRORIGNORE YES "+"\n";
media_raw +="URL GOTO=http://www.website.com/share/index.php "+"\n";
media_raw +="TAG POS=1 TYPE=SPAN ATTR=CLASS:media_row EXTRACT=TXT     "+"\n";
media_raw +="SET !VAR1 {{!EXTRACT}} "+"\n";

iimPlay(media_raw)

var raw = iimGetLastExtract();

for(var i=0;i<raw;i++)
{
iimPlay("fb.iim")
iimPlay("twitter.iim")
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the `parseInt()` function:

```
var raw = parseInt(iimGetLastExtract());
```